# Connecting Push Button to function on different tab using PyQt5

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to connect a push button to a function on a different tab, I have been searching for a solution to this but can't make any progress, I have included a simplified version of the code below. Basically, I would like for the QPushButton on Tab1 to be connected to the plot_show function on Tab2. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc


class  Tab1(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.resize(1000,850)
        self.button1 = qtw.QPushButton("Plot")
        
        #self.button1.clicked.connect(??????)????? # connect this to the plot_show function on Tab2
        
        main_layout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button1)

class Tab2(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.x=[1,2,3]
        self.y=[4,5,6]

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.plotWidget=FigureCanvas(self.fig)
            
        main_layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.plotWidget)

    def plot_show(self):
        self.ax.plot(self.x,self.y)

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.tabs = qtw.QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

        self.tab1=Tab1()
        self.tab2=Tab2()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab 1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab 2")

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Make the connection in `MainWindow.__init__`, where you have a reference to both tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, from your code I did a quick fix to achieve what you ask, just put `self.tab1.button1.clicked.connect(self.tab2.plot_show)` in your MainWindow class:

```py
class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.tabs = qtw.QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

        self.tab1 = Tab1()
        self.tab2 = Tab2()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab 1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab 2")

        self.tab1.button1.clicked.connect(self.tab2.plot_show)
        self.show()
```

Click the button, change the tab and your plot is in tab2. Thus, you have to make the connections from a common place like MainWindow, or use the principles of inheritance. I hope this can serve as a start for your code.

Also note that you do not need to make a new class for the tabs added to QTabsWidget.